# 2002 Subaru Outback strange starting

Tags: subaru, ignition, starter, security, outback

my 2002 Subaru Outback has an anti theft starter system where if I turn the key nothing happens, but if I turn the key and also press the windshield wiper de-icer then the call will start. This is how I bought it and didn’t really look into it too much, but just recently it will make terrible clicking noises when I go over bumps. Is this just a case of mis wiring or is this just an aftermarket security system that the car has?